# Server returns invalid timezone. Go to Advanced tab and set servertimezone property manually

Tags: mysql, sql, database, intellij-idea, mysql-workbench

My Intelij IDE wont connect to my database server of MySQL Workbench, it specifies it as a timezone problem and wants me to go to advanced tab and set serverTimezone property manually.

I tried looking if there where a similar problem but i cant seem to find it.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't find [this dialog](https://i.imgur.com/kmMgJ8T.png)?

Comment: Setting the paramter to UTC fixed it for me too. Interesting reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql

Answer (score 233, accepted):

In the **Database** tool window, right click on the data source, choose **Properties** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>), click on the **Advanced** tab.

Set the `serverTimezone` property to `UTC`.

See also the corresponding [documentation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html#advancedTab).

[image: Advanced]

Comment: A little hidden in the answer but this helped me. Setting the paramter to UTC fixed it for me.

Answer (score 16):

@CrazyCoder is correct but here is a more details answer:

In DataGrip right click on your `database` drop down menu click on `Properties` then go to Advanced and slowly look for severTimeZone as in this attachement below:

[image]

Don't forget to click on apply and test again it should work.

Done.

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem. Running

`SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+8:00';`

on MySql command line solved the problem!

Answer (score 3):

You need to set 'serverTimezone' with 'UTC'. But use upper case!

Open Properties, in mac use (Command + ;), click on the Advanced tab.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[You can follow the picture find the configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Cgw.png) , Set Time zone = UTC

Comment: Please, add more details to your answer.